# jython script doesnt start when run in background

Tags: jython, daemon, background-process

I have a Jython script that is meant to run as a daemon in background, but somehow it doesn't start at all when I'm trying to run it in background.

So I've tried to do a most basic "hello world" script, it works fine if I execute it in console like

`./mysqript.py`

But same script executed like

`./mysqript.py &`

fails. It doesn't output error messages, it doesn't throw exceptions, it's actually not even quitting silently. It's just hanging forever in the process list as a zombie process doing nothing.

Why is that and how can I make it work?

PS: Environment is Jython2.7 beta.

Comment: do you see a Java process for your command in the process list? If yes, try "kill -3 <pid>"  on that process and see what you get.